# How to rbind a single number with a matrix in R

Tags: r

I tried with the following code

```
rbind(1, matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    6
[3,]    2    7
[4,]    3    8
[5,]    4    9
[6,]    5   10
```

but I wish to get output like below

```
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1    
    [2,]    1    6
    [3,]    2    7
    [4,]    3    8
    [5,]    4    9
    [6,]    5   10
```

Comment: You need to include a value in that space, or NA, but you cannot bind a vector that has less columns than the original (or conversely less rows if you are adding a column)

Answer (score 3):

`cbind` a single vector with `NA` and then use `rbind`

```
rbind(cbind(1, NA),matrix(1:10, 5))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   NA
#[2,]    1    6
#[3,]    2    7
#[4,]    3    8
#[5,]    4    9
#[6,]    5   10
```

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of getting the exact output, we can do the following(see the note below):

```
noquote(rbind(c(1,""),matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 5)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1        
[2,] 1    6   
[3,] 2    7   
[4,] 3    8   
[5,] 4    9   
[6,] 5    10
```

**NOTE**

1. Using `""` to introduce a blank will lead to coercion to character.
2. We could use `as.numeric` to have numerics but this would lead to `NA`s which has already been demonstrated.
3. Using `NA` instead of `""` is more realistic and useful